# How to remove bottom and top border from a row overflowing to the next page in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word

When a row overflows to the next page, I would like the bottom/top border to be transparent. Reason being, I would like to preserve a sense of continuity. Is it possible?

In the picture below, the bottom/top border I meant is indicated in the blue box:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways i hope this will help you to resolve yours question!
**Option 1:** 
The only way to get it done was to put a column break (CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER) in so that the table is no longer continuous.

Click in the top cell of the table in page 2 and put the break in there. 
Then by selecting the last cells on page 1 and using '**borders and shading' with apply to cell** took out the last line.

Doing the same to put the top line in on the second page.

interestingly it looks like there is no line at the top of the table on the second page - go to print preview and you will see that there is!

**Option 2:**

1. Go to border and shading and DE-select bottom line of the first page each column cell.
2. Then go to next row cell then De-select top line of that each column cell then enter your data in that so while printing or converting into pdf you wont see the first page table bottom line and second page table top line.

Hope this helps you ....

Thanks & Regards,
Krishna Pavan YNV
M:+91-8179828425